# MDIparent in Winform Application return Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, plugins, mdiparent

I have a problem with this code. You can find all classes [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/Generic-plug-in-application-in-C.aspx).

If I launch the application and I want open a new Form i receive this error:

> NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The main application is set to `isMDIcontainer = true;`

Now I received the error in this part of code:

```
private void PluginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menu = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    Plugin.PluginForm form = ((PluginInfo)menu.Tag).CreateInstance();
    form.MdiParent = this;   // Here is thrown the error
    form.Show();
}
```

`Plugin.PluginForm` is only an Extended Form. This is the `CreateIstance()` method:

```
public PluginForm CreateInstance()
{
    if (!File.Exists(FileName))
        return null;

    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(FileName);
    foreach (Type type in ass.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.BaseType == typeof(PluginForm))
        {
           return (PluginForm)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the same sebsite someone says that this error could may be resolved in this way:

> You must declare property system.window.form parentForm in interface

but I didn't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are good that `CreateInstance` is returning a `null` because the `FileName` is wrong (incorrect filename or path).

The result of it returning a `null` is that the `form` variable is `null` and any member access on it (as in `form.MdiParent` will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Make sure that the filename is correct and that the file exists in the path it is searched on.

Comment: Yes , the problem was that there was already a installed plugin and the path was different from mine.